# Getting an invariant violation when trying to rendering react-navigation AppContainer

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to get started with react-navigation 3.0.9 but I'm having issues rendering the Router component.

Here is my `router/index.js` file

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

import Login from '../screens/Login';

const Routes = createStackNavigator({
  Login
});

const Router = createAppContainer(Routes)

export default Router;
```

Then here is my `App.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import { Platform, StatusBar, StyleSheet, View, TextInput, Text } from 'react-native';

import { Router } from './router'

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <Router />
    )
  }
}
```

Here is my `screens/Login.js` file

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

export default class Login extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <View>
        <Text>Hello World</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

The error I receive in Expo tells me the Element type is invalid (Invariant violation), and says I should check the render method of App.

Am I not importing/exporting the Router correctly?

Answer (score 1):

The router import should not be destructured

In App.js change:

```
import { Router } from './router'
```

to

```
import Router from './router'
```

Answer (score 0):

in your **router/index.js** file, change this part:

```
import Login from '../screens/Login';

const Routes = createStackNavigator({
    Login: { screen: Login }    // Just changed this line
});
```

---

Also in you **App.js** import `Router` as:

```
import Router from './router'
```

c/o: **[jermainecraig](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56238882/7109362)'s answer**